# How to sort the row of a 2d matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array, vector

this is my code

```
cin >> n;

    vector<vector<int>> A(n, vector<int>(n));

    for (auto &row : A)
        for (auto &el : row)
            cin >> el;

    for (auto row : A)
        sort(row.begin(), row.end());

    for (auto row : A)
    {
        for (auto el : row)
            cout << el << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
```

for example if the input is :

```
3 ///3 by 3 matrix
1 2 3
2 1 3
3 2 1
```

the output should be:

```
1 2 3 
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

my code gives me the same input and i don t know how to fix it.

Comment: There's a very important difference between the first loop (`for (auto &row : A)`) and the second (`for (auto row : A)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate using reference, not a copy while calling `std::sort`. Also, while printing it is better to use the reference as copying each row incurs a penalty of `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of elements in that row.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; // this is not a good practice.

int main() {
    int n; 
    cin >> n;
    vector<vector<int>> A(n, vector<int>(n));
    for (auto &row : A)
        for (auto &el : row)
            cin >> el;
    for (auto &row : A) //change this line
        sort(row.begin(), row.end());
    for (auto &row : A)
    {
        for (auto &el : row)
            cout << el << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The asker has asked me to provide the code to sort the matrix by column. Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

void input_matrix(auto &x) {
    for (auto &i : x)
        for (auto &j : i)
            std::cin >> j;
}

void output_matrix(auto &x) {
    for (auto &i : x) {
        for (auto &j : i)
            std::cout << j << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void transpose_matrix(auto &x) {
    size_t n = x.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            std::swap(x[i][j], x[j][i]);
}

void sort_matrix_by_row(auto &x) {
    for (auto &i : x)
        std::sort(i.begin(), i.end());
}

void sort_matrix_by_col(auto &x) {
    transpose_matrix(x);
    sort_matrix_by_row(x);
    transpose_matrix(x);
} 

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> A(n, std::vector<int>(n));
    input_matrix(A);
    sort_matrix_by_col(A);
    output_matrix(A);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: also I do I sort each column of the matrix  ``````bool myfunction(vector<int> i, vector<int> j) {
    return (i[2] < j[2]);
}``````  but this function does only the second column. I need all the column  sorted.

Comment: @MogovanJonathan You can do a transpose then sort by row then again do a transpose. This is the far most easiest way to do so.

Comment: could you edit your answer and add the method, cause I can t figure it how. Thanks!

Comment: @MogovanJonathan give me about 5 mins, I will add it.

Comment: have you succeeded?

Comment: @MogovanJonathan Check the answer. I had edited it.

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
for (auto& row : A)
    sort(row.begin(), row.end());
```

You are trying to change the rows, so you need a reference to the original row. Your code is just sorting a copy of the row.